# How to parse json data using volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am using volley lib. at every activities in my project my first login page has done using volley JSON Object Request method(POST) and next activities could not parsed.

Json data of the main screen:

```
{
"err-code": 5,
  "job_details": [
    {
      "job_id": 33,
      "job_no": "ES53-AF",
      "contract_manager_id": 4,
      "company_name": "A Construction  Ltd",
      "time_spent": 4.5
    },
    {
      "job_id": 5,
      "job_no": "ES1465-AF",
      "contract_manager_id": 4,
      "company_name": "Trios Property",
      "job_description": "Carry out the rewire of ",
      "time_spent": 26.5
    },
    {
      "job_id": 81,
      "job_no": "ES101-AF",
      "contract_manager_id": 4,
      "company_name": "Arden Construction  Ltd",
      "job_description": "Carry out works as per esti 3AQ",
      "time_spent": 2.5
    },
  }]
}
```

Code:

```
private  void getDataNew()
{
   String url = "http://103.5.103.8:067/ivservices/Webservices/joblisting";
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    String token = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_TOKEN);
    Log.e("token check kro", token);
    final String role = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ROLE);
    Log.e("role", role);
    String user_id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERID);
 // Log.e("user_id", user_id.toString());
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
    params.put(KEY_TOKEN, token);
    params.put(KEY_ROLE, role);
    params.put(KEY_ID, user_id);

        JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject(params);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, parameters, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
               // Log.e("response mila", response.toString());
                parseData(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                error.printStackTrace();
                //TODO: handle failure
            }
        });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parsing data from JSON using Volley in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699988/parsing-data-from-json-using-volley-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove Extra }, from your json.

one mistake you did in json parsing code you replied to @Er. Arjun saini .

that mistake is in this line :

JSONArray jsonArray = Object.getJSONArray("**err-code**");

it should be like this :

JSONArray jsonArray = Object.getJSONArray("**job_details**");

Make sure json should be like this:

```
    {


"err-code": 5,
  "job_details": [
    {
      "job_id": 33,
      "job_no": "ES53-AF",
      "contract_manager_id": 4,
      "company_name": "A Construction  Ltd",
      "time_spent": 4.5
    },
    {
      "job_id": 5,
      "job_no": "ES1465-AF",
      "contract_manager_id": 4,
      "company_name": "Trios Property",
      "job_description": "Carry out the rewire of ",
      "time_spent": 26.5
    },


{
  "job_id": 81,
  "job_no": "ES101-AF",
  "contract_manager_id": 4,
  "company_name": "Arden Construction  Ltd",
  "job_description": "Carry out works as per esti 3AQ",
  "time_spent": 2.5
}
  ]
}
```

And Try this code hope it will work if not work than please share logcat errors and exceptions

```
try {
        JSONObject Object=new JSONObject(response);
        int code = Object.getInt("err-code");
        if (code == 0) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = Object.getJSONArray("job_details");
            List<JobList> jobListArray=new ArrayList<JobList>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.length(); i++) { 
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                JobList model_joblist=new JobList();
                model_joblist.setJobno(jsonObject.getString(JobList.JOB_NO));
                model_joblist.setJobid(jsonObject.getInt(JobList.JOB_ID));
                model_joblist.setDescreption(jsonObject.getString(JobList.JOB_DESCRIPTION));
                jobListArray.add(model_joblist);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

if it still not work than there is error in any other code e.g. in json are in your model_joblist etc.

share more code and logcat please.

Comment: hi ..i have another question...how can l implement my android app..for admin home screen different and users home screen different except login screen in same app

Comment: one solution could be :
you can make different screen for user and admin.
on login check if login is of admin then move him to admin activities and so on.... otherwise open users activities.....

Second solution if you have same screens but different data then after checking user or admin load relevant data....
Try which suits in your.....

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

> **Note**  Check Also your json remove ,} before ] than you have without syntax error response

```
 try {

        int err_code=response.getInt("err-code");

        JSONArray jsonArray=response.getJSONArray("job_details");
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObjectdetail=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            int job_id=jsonObjectdetail.getInt("job_id");
            int time_spent=jsonObjectdetail.getInt("time_spent");
            int contract_manager_id=jsonObjectdetail.getInt("contract_manager_id");
            String job_no=jsonObjectdetail.getString("job_no");
            String company_name=jsonObjectdetail.getString("company_name");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: String job_no=jsonObjectdetail.getString("job_no");
no response getting at this line

Comment: sorry change response.getInt("err-code");.... See update answer now you get

Comment: Before there is err_code so not get change it as according to your json

Comment: Have You  problem Yet

Comment: have you change the your response i mention in Note: